# Link to another list (not full list, results only meet some condition) when fields in specific colum are clicked

Tags: react-admin

Im using

```
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-admin": "^3.6.0",
```

what I try to do is that when specific column's field(list A) is clicked, go to another List B.

for example,
List A has columns (ProductId, ProductModel, Product Version, In Stock, Out of Stock, Disposal)

if 'In stock' fields are clicked, is has to go to List B filtered by that row's product Id and status is 'In stock'.

if 'Out Of stock' fields are clicked, is has to go to List B filtered by that row's product Id and status is 'Out of stock'.

using reference fields for 'In stock' and 'Out of Stock' is not appropriate. because there is no api only for them.

and I tried with hitory.push('List B') but it just show full list of List B.

what should I do this case???

Answer (score 1):

This is actually documented in the react-admin `<List>` component documentation, section 'Linking to a pre-filtered list' (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#linking-to-a-pre-filtered-list).

As the filter values are taken from the URL, you can link to a pre-filtered list by setting the query parameter.

For instance, if you have a list of tags, you can display a button for each category to link to the list of posts filtered by that tag:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { stringify } from 'query-string';

const LinkToRelatedProducts = ({ record }) => {
    const translate = useTranslate();
    return record ? (
        <Button
            color="primary"
            component={Link}
            to={{
                pathname: '/posts',
                search: stringify({
                    page: 1,
                    perPage: 25,
                    sort: 'id',
                    order: 'DESC',
                    filter: JSON.stringify({ category_id: record.id }),
                }),
            }}
        >
            All posts with the category {record.name} ; 
        </Button>
    ) : null;
};
```

You can use this button e.g. as a child of . You can also create a custom Menu button with that technique to link to the unfiltered list by setting the filter value to {}.

Tip: You have to pass all the query string parameters - not just filter. That’s a current limitation of react-admin.